# DynamoDB - Add existing table to a global table replica

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

Is there a way to add an existing table in another region ( same name, same indexes, same keys - in fact built from the exact same cloudformation template) to the replica list of a global table?

I did try adding the table to the replica list, but failed with below exception,

`botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateTable operation: Failed to create a the new replica of table with name: ‘dev_xxxx_dax_configs’ because one or more replicas already existed as tables.`

Note: Source and destination tables are exactly same in its structure, except the region it belongs to.
Trying to use the 2019 version of global table.